# Wizard pattern vs. Accordion pattern in a long form

Tags: forms, wizard, accordion

**Wizard pattern (multi-step) vs. Accordion pattern in a single long form?**

Q1. What is the best pattern to chose for the following scenario

**Scenario** 
In an Admin console, Admin have to create an account and assign product and users.

Q2. What would be best way to define the task
First - Create account and stop
Second - view the details of account
Third - Add products and users

OR
Try to accomplish all the steps in one go using wizard pattern.

I am trying to retain law of continuity and Hick's law here by using Wizard.  But open for suggestions.

I have found one similar topic on this page [big form VS steps/wizard](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56481/big-form-vs-steps-wizard), but not much of deciding or convincing answers or any research findings are shared.  If anyone have any research based findings, then please share.  If you can share the respective article / research findings / blogs urls that will help.

Thanks.  Look forward for the discussion.

Comment: can you define what you see the exact difference between a wizard and accordion is?

Comment: Wizard divide simple and complex tasks into a series of steps, with the goal of reducing the probability of user error.  They function by reducing the skill level required to complete each task.  Where as an accordion is a grouped set of collapsible panels that the user can open and close by hovering on or clicking on the title of a specific panel. Accordion allows organizing the content into logical, titled sections in a space-saving way.

Comment: To me, the question is confusing; your version of what a wizard is and an accordion form are one of the same, both "divide simple and complex tasks into a series of steps".

Comment: Besides Wizard & Accordion, what other types of forms are there ?

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than looking at the scenario you should look at the design principle and rationale between the use of wizard versus accordion patterns and work out what interaction or behaviour you want to achieve. The main take home points for me would be:

- Is the process linear or can people skip steps or save and come back to it later?
- Do you have a lot of content, very little content or variable amounts of content? What would be the best way to present the optimum amount of information to the user?
- Where does this fit into the rest of the page design, like help information or guidance tools/widgets?